# How to rate limit by HTTP status code with HAProxy?

Tags: haproxy

HAProxy provides a built-in `http_err_rate` counter which “reports the average HTTP request error rate over that period.” This can be used in a stick table to rate-limit clients that are generating a lot of errors. That might look something like this:

```
frontend web
  tcp-request content reject if { src_get_gpc0(Abuse) gt 0 }
  acl scanner src_http_err_rate(Abuse) ge 10
  http-request deny if scanner flag_abuser

backend Abuse
  stick-table type ip size 1m expire 60m store gpc0,http_err_rate(20s)
```

What I'd like to do is track something like the `http_err_rate`, but only for `401 Unauthorized` status codes. That way HAProxy would only be concerned with rate-limiting unauthorized requests, rather than all HTTP error codes.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

> What I'd like to do is track something like the http_err_rate, but only for 401 Unauthorized status codes.

You can use the [General Purpose Counters](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.9/configuration.html#7.3.3-sc0_gpc0_rate) together with an ACL matching on the [`status`](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.9/configuration.html#7.3.6-status) fetch. The following example configuration will track the rate of 404 errors for a given IP address [1] and deny requests with the 429 status if a rate of 10 requests per 10 seconds is exceeded:

```
frontend fe_http
    mode http
    bind *:8080

    stick-table type ipv6 size 10k expire 300s store gpc0_rate(10s)
    http-request  track-sc0 src
    http-request  deny deny_status 429 if { sc0_gpc0_rate gt 10 }
    # Relevant line below
    http-response sc-inc-gpc0(0) if { status 404 }

    default_backend be_http

backend be_http
    mode http
    server example example.com:80
```

[1] Note: I recommend to use `ipv6` as the stick table key, it may contain both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to rate limit depending on their rate of 401 you need to change the 429 code by 401 in your config:

```
http-request deny deny_status 401 if { sc_http_req_cnt(0) gt 10 }
```

> With both deny and tarpit you can add the deny_status flag to set a
>   custom response code instead of the default 403/500 that they use out
>   of the box. For example using http-request deny deny_status 429 will
>   cause HAProxy to respond to the client with the error 429: Too Many
>   Requests.

For more "general" information about acls and rate-limiting, you can see:

https://www.haproxy.com/blog/four-examples-of-haproxy-rate-limiting/
https://www.haproxy.com/blog/introduction-to-haproxy-acls/